# tailwind classes not working in vue with custom colors

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

i'm making a web App that allows users to change the accent color of the app and adding background tailwind classes debending on the accent color that the user have choosed but it's not working, when i use :style="" attribute evry thing works fine
here is what i'm trying to do

```
          <button
            class="h-full w-10/12 mt-4 text-lg rounded-md text-white disabled:bg-gray-300 dark:disabled:bg-gray-700"
            :disabled="isFormValid === false ? true : false"
            :class="isFormValid === true ? `bg-[${accentColor}]` : false"
            >
          Button
          </button>
```

and here is when using :style="" attribute it works perfect

```
          <button
            class="h-full w-10/12 mt-4 text-lg rounded-md text-white disabled:bg-gray-300 dark:disabled:bg-gray-700"
            :disabled="isFormValid === false ? true : false"
            :style="
              isFormValid === true ? `background-color:${accentColor};` : false
            "
          >
            Button
          </button>
```

i'm making sure that accentColor is returning A string but i want to know if tailwind doesn't support this or i'm missing somthing?

Comment: Use style attribute - see [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to happen. You can try the `bg-[#1da1f2]` class. Could your `accentColor` variable even miss the `#` character?

Comment: yes it has the # character , when opening the inspecter the code looks like this bg-[#358f80] i don't think there is a wrong with it